# Combine several rows into one observation

Tags: stata

I have a dataset in Stata where one observation is spread out over multiple rows like the table below. The variables are string except for the id, and there exist some duplicate entries for some variables (like the last row in the table).

| id | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |  |  |
| 1 |  | name2 |  |
| 1 |  |  | name3 |
| 2 | name4 |  |  |
| 2 |  | name5 |  |
| 3 | name6 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  | name8 |
| 3 |  |  | name9 |

I want to take the first value and combine all variables to one row / observation. I think this is a really easy task but somehow I don't manage to figure it out.

| id | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | name2 | name3 |
| 2 | name4 | name5 |  |
| 3 | name6 |  | name8 |

Comment: Terminology can be a nightmare. Here your problem is that _several_ observations may refer to the same individual and if so they need to be combined in single observations. Stata doesn't know the term _row_ in this context except as another word for _observation_. (Matrices are different and talking about rowwise operations is an exception.)

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume as implied in text that `name9` is really the same as `name8`. That being so, here is one solution.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte id str5(var1 var2 var3)
1 "name1" ""      ""     
1 ""      "name2" ""     
1 ""      ""      "name3"
2 "name4" ""      ""     
2 ""      "name5" ""     
3 "name6" ""      ""     
3 ""      ""      "name8"
3 ""      ""      "name8"
end

forval j = 1/3 { 
    bysort id (var`j') : replace var`j' = var`j'[_N]
}

duplicates drop 


     +----------------------------+
     | id    var1    var2    var3 |
     |----------------------------|
  1. |  1   name1   name2   name3 |
  2. |  2   name4   name5         |
  3. |  3   name6           name8 |
     +----------------------------+
```

EDIT In the event that what is wanted is the first non-missing string value, `collapse` remains the solution of choice, but here is a solution without it.

```
clear
input byte id str5(var1 var2 var3)
1 "name1" ""      ""     
1 ""      "name2" ""     
1 ""      ""      "name3"
2 "name4" ""      ""     
2 ""      "name5" ""     
3 "name6" ""      ""     
3 ""      ""      "name8"
3 ""      ""      "name9"
end

gen long obsno = _n 
forval j = 1/3 {
    bysort id : egen firstnm = min(cond(var`j' != "", obsno, .))
    replace var`j' = var`j'[firstnm]
    drop firstnm
} 

drop obsno 

duplicates drop 

list
```

Comment: No, name8 and name9 is not the same. I'm using firm collateral data with 8 different variables. Var3 in the table corresponds to the value/s of outstanding collateral i.e. a firm can have several collaterals.

Comment: You said that the last row in the table was a duplicate!  I will add another solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `collapse`'s service here.

```
collapse (firstnm) var*, by(id)
```

Comment: This is better. `firstnm` does support string arguments.